# Highcharts, add 'go back' (drill up) button when drill

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How to implement that '< Go back' button from this http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Vf3yT/ (click on pie) to this http://jsfiddle.net/neFYY/ (new 3.0 Highcharts) ?

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        drillUpText: '◁ Back to {series.name}'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make it clear:

- this example: http://jsfiddle.net/neFYY/2/ IS NOT plugin, it's just simple Highcharts chart, with some click binds to make it behave like drilldown.
- this example: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Vf3yT/ IS plugin, which requires some specific structure to make it work (see: `drilldown` object)

So if you want to use plugin with first chart, you need to pass proper structure for that plugin, which is:

```
drilldown: {
    activeAxisLabelStyle: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        color: '#039',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textDecoration: 'underline'            
    },
    activeDataLabelStyle: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        color: '#039',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textDecoration: 'underline'            
    },
    animation: {
        duration: 500
    },
    series: [{
        id: 'fruits',
        name: 'Fruits',
        data: [
            ['Apples', 4],
            ['Pears', 6],
            ['Oranges', 2],
            ['Grapes', 8]
        ]
    }, {
        id: 'cars',
        name: 'Cars',
        data: [{
            name: 'Toyota', 
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'toyota'
        },
        ['Volkswagen', 3],
        ['Opel', 5]
        ]
    }, {
        id: 'toyota',
        name: 'Toyota',
        data: [
            ['RAV4', 3],
            ['Corolla', 1],
            ['Carina', 4],
            ['Land Cruiser', 5]
        ]
    }]
},
```

And series:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Overview',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Fruits',
        y: 10,
        drilldown: 'fruits'
    }, {
        name: 'Cars',
        y: 12,
        drilldown: 'cars'
    }, {
        name: 'Countries',
        y: 8
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what plugin you are speaking about in the second example?

Comment: Sure, I mean drilldown.js plugin for Highcharts, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown) (on top).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the problem is, to add button you can use `plugin`  http://jsfiddle.net/Vf3yT/62

Top chart from fisrt example is the same as second fiddle.

Comment: because when i add drilldown module to this chart it disappears http://jsfiddle.net/neFYY/1/

Comment: But this first chart is the same, only difference is datalabel (percent) so http://jsfiddle.net/Vf3yT/63/ and yours are the same.

Comment: any ideas? When i remove drilldown module in http://jsfiddle.net/neFYY/1/ charts are shown but i need to get that '<  Go back' button