# Highcharts - drill down to multiple series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a parent chart that I need to drill down to a child chart with multiple series.  Here is a *toy exampl*e of what I would like to do.  (I know this does not work)

> Notice I'm trying to pass in an array of ids to display in the child chart.

Does anybody know a way to do this?  If someone from Highcharts reads this, can this be added as a feature?

```
$(function () {    

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column : {
            stacking : 'normal'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Yearly Orders',
        data: [{
            name: 'Location 1',
            y: 100,
            drilldown: ['l1-wa', 'l1-wb']
        }, {
            name: 'Location 2',
            y: 150,
            drilldown: ['l2-wa', 'l2-wb']
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Widget A',
            type: 'line',
            id: 'l1-wa',
            data: [
                {name: 'Qtr 1', y: 5},
                {name: 'Qtr 2', y: 25},
                {name: 'Qtr 3', y: 25},
                {name: 'Qtr 4', y: 20}
            ]
        },{
            name: 'Widget B',
            type: 'line',
            id: 'l1-wb',
            data: [
                {name: 'Qtr 1', y: 10},
                {name: 'Qtr 2', y: 5},
                {name: 'Qtr 3', y: 5},
                {name: 'Qtr 4', y: 5}
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Widget A',
            type: 'line',
            id: 'l2-wa',
            data: [
                {name: 'Qtr 1', y: 25},
                {name: 'Qtr 2', y: 5},
                {name: 'Qtr 3', y: 5},
                {name: 'Qtr 4', y: 15}
            ]
        },{
            name: 'Widget B',
            type: 'line',
            id: 'l2-wb',
            data: [
                {name: 'Qtr 1', y: 30},
                {name: 'Qtr 2', y: 30},
                {name: 'Qtr 3', y: 15},
                {name: 'Qtr 4', y: 25}
            ]
        } 

                ]
    }
})
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle of this drilling down to just one series http://jsfiddle.net/F7z3D/2/

**EDIT - I extended Highcharts to give me some enhanced changes when drilling down. This is probably not the best code, but gets the point across.  This allows for changing of the x and y axes, changing the subtitle, and multiple series.**

```
 $(function () {

 (function (H) {
     var noop = function () {},
     defaultOptions = H.getOptions(),
         each = H.each,
         extend = H.extend,
         format = H.format,
         wrap = H.wrap,
         Chart = H.Chart,
         seriesTypes = H.seriesTypes,
         PieSeries = seriesTypes.pie,
         ColumnSeries = seriesTypes.column,
         fireEvent = HighchartsAdapter.fireEvent,
         inArray = HighchartsAdapter.inArray;

     H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'drillUp', function (proceed) {

         var chart = this,
             drilldownLevels = chart.drilldownLevels,
             levelNumber = drilldownLevels[drilldownLevels.length - 1].levelNumber,
             i = drilldownLevels.length,
             chartSeries = chart.series,
             seriesI = chartSeries.length,
             level,
             oldSeries,
             newSeries,
             oldExtremes,
             addSeries = function (seriesOptions) {
                 var addedSeries;
                 each(chartSeries, function (series) {
                     if (series.userOptions === seriesOptions) {
                         addedSeries = series;
                     }
                 });

                 addedSeries = addedSeries || chart.addSeries(seriesOptions, false);
                 if (addedSeries.type === oldSeries.type && addedSeries.animateDrillupTo) {
                     addedSeries.animate = addedSeries.animateDrillupTo;
                 }
                 if (seriesOptions === level.seriesOptions) {
                     newSeries = addedSeries;
                 }
             };


         while (i--) {

             level = drilldownLevels[i];
              console.log(level.levelNumber);
             console.log(levelNumber);
             if (level.levelNumber === levelNumber) {
                 drilldownLevels.pop();

                 // Get the lower series by reference or id
                 oldSeries = level.lowerSeries;

                 if ($.isArray(oldSeries)) {

    if (chart.series) {
        while (chart.series.length > 0) {
            chart.series[0].remove(false);
        }
    }


                     if (level.levelSubtitle) {
                         chart.setTitle(null, {text: level.levelSubtitle});
                     } else {
                         chart.setTitle(null, {
                             text: ''
                         });
                     }

                     if (chart.xAxis && level.levelXAxis) {
                         while (chart.xAxis.length > 0) {
                             chart.xAxis[0].remove(false);
                         }
                     }
                     if (chart.yAxis && level.levelYAxis) {
                         while (chart.yAxis.length > 0) {
                             chart.yAxis[0].remove(false);
                         }
                     }

                     if (level.levelYAxis) {
                         $.each(level.levelYAxis, function () {
                             chart.addAxis(this, false, false);
                         });
                     }
                     if (level.levelXAxis) {
                         $.each(level.levelXAxis, function () {
                             chart.addAxis(this, true, false);
                         });
                     }
                     $.each(level.levelSeriesOptions, function () {
                         chart.addSeries(this, false);
                     });


                 } else {
                     if (!oldSeries.chart) { // #2786
                         while (seriesI--) {
                             if (chartSeries[seriesI].options.id === level.lowerSeriesOptions.id) {
                                 oldSeries = chartSeries[seriesI];
                                 break;
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     oldSeries.xData = []; // Overcome problems with minRange (#2898)

                     each(level.levelSeriesOptions, addSeries);

                     fireEvent(chart, 'drillup', {
                         seriesOptions: level.seriesOptions
                     });

                     if (newSeries.type === oldSeries.type) {
                         newSeries.drilldownLevel = level;
                         newSeries.options.animation = chart.options.drilldown.animation;

                         if (oldSeries.animateDrillupFrom) {
                             oldSeries.animateDrillupFrom(level);
                         }
                     }

                     newSeries.levelNumber = levelNumber;

                     oldSeries.remove(false);

                     // Reset the zoom level of the upper series
                     if (newSeries.xAxis) {
                         oldExtremes = level.oldExtremes;
                         newSeries.xAxis.setExtremes(oldExtremes.xMin, oldExtremes.xMax, false);
                         newSeries.yAxis.setExtremes(oldExtremes.yMin, oldExtremes.yMax, false);
                     }

                 }
             }
         }

         this.redraw();


         if (this.drilldownLevels.length === 0) {
             console.log('destroy');
             this.drillUpButton = this.drillUpButton.destroy();
         } else {
             console.log('no destroy '+this.drilldownLevels.length);
             this.drillUpButton.attr({
                 text: this.getDrilldownBackText()
             })
                 .align();
         }

     });

     H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown', function (proceed, point, ddOptions) {

         if (!ddOptions.series) {
             proceed.call(this, point, ddOptions);
         } else {

             var thisChart = this;

             var oldSeries = point.series,
                 xAxis = oldSeries.xAxis,
                 yAxis = oldSeries.yAxis,
                 color = point.color || oldSeries.color,
                 pointIndex,
                 levelSeries = [],
                 levelSeriesOptions = [],
                 levelXAxis = [],
                 levelYAxis = [],
                 levelSubtitle,
                 level,
                 levelNumber;

             levelNumber = oldSeries.levelNumber || 0;

         //    ddOptions.series[0] = extend({
          //       color: color
         //    }, ddOptions.series[0]);
         //    pointIndex = inArray(point, oldSeries.points);

             // Record options for all current series
             each(oldSeries.chart.series, function (series) {
                 if (series.xAxis === xAxis) {
                     levelSeries.push(series);
                     levelSeriesOptions.push(series.userOptions);
                     series.levelNumber = series.levelNumber || 0;
                 }
             });

             each(oldSeries.chart.xAxis, function (xAxis) {
                 levelXAxis.push(xAxis.userOptions);
             });

             each(oldSeries.chart.yAxis, function (yAxis) {
                 levelYAxis.push(yAxis.userOptions);
             });


             if(oldSeries.chart.subtitle && oldSeries.chart.subtitle.textStr){
                 levelSubtitle = oldSeries.chart.subtitle.textStr;
                 console.log(levelSubtitle);
             }

             // Add a record of properties for each drilldown level
             level = {
                 levelNumber: levelNumber,
                 seriesOptions: oldSeries.userOptions,
                 levelSeriesOptions: levelSeriesOptions,
                 levelSeries: levelSeries,
                 levelXAxis: levelXAxis,
                 levelYAxis: levelYAxis,
                 levelSubtitle: levelSubtitle,
                 shapeArgs: point.shapeArgs,
                 bBox: point.graphic.getBBox(),
                 color: color,
                 lowerSeriesOptions: ddOptions,
                 pointOptions: oldSeries.options.data[pointIndex],
                 pointIndex: pointIndex,
                 oldExtremes: {
                     xMin: xAxis && xAxis.userMin,
                     xMax: xAxis && xAxis.userMax,
                     yMin: yAxis && yAxis.userMin,
                     yMax: yAxis && yAxis.userMax
                 }
             };

             // Generate and push it to a lookup array
             if (!this.drilldownLevels) {
                 this.drilldownLevels = [];
             }
             this.drilldownLevels.push(level);

             level.lowerSeries = [];

             if (ddOptions.subtitle) {
                 this.setTitle(null, {text: ddOptions.subtitle});
             }else{
                 this.setTitle(null, {text: ''});
             }

             if (this.xAxis && ddOptions.xAxis) {
                 while (this.xAxis.length > 0) {
                     this.xAxis[0].remove(false);
                 }
             }
             if (this.yAxis && ddOptions.yAxis) {
                 while (this.yAxis.length > 0) {
                     this.yAxis[0].remove(false);
                 }
             }


             if (ddOptions.yAxis) {
                 if ($.isArray(ddOptions.yAxis)) {
                     $.each(ddOptions.yAxis, function () {
                         thisChart.addAxis(this, false, false);
                     });
                 } else {
                     thisChart.addAxis(ddOptions.yAxis, false, false);
                 }
             }
             if (ddOptions.xAxis) {
                 if ($.isArray(ddOptions.xAxis)) {
                     $.each(ddOptions.xAxis, function () {
                         thisChart.addAxis(this, true, false);
                     });
                 } else {
                     thisChart.addAxis(ddOptions.xAxis, true, false);
                 }

             }



             $.each(ddOptions.series, function () {

                 var newSeries = thisChart.addSeries(this, true);
                 level.lowerSeries.push(newSeries);
                 newSeries.levelNumber = levelNumber + 1;
     //            if (xAxis) {
    //                 xAxis.oldPos = xAxis.pos;
       //              xAxis.userMin = xAxis.userMax = null;
        //             yAxis.userMin = yAxis.userMax = null;
          //       }

            //     // Run fancy cross-animation on supported and equal types
             //    if (oldSeries.type === newSeries.type) {
              //       newSeries.animate = newSeries.animateDrilldown || noop;
              //       newSeries.options.animation = true;
               //  }
             });



         }
     });

     H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'doDrilldown', function (proceed, _holdRedraw) {

         if (!$.isPlainObject(this.drilldown)) {
             proceed.call(this, _holdRedraw);
         } else {
             var ddChartConfig = this.drilldown;
             console.log(ddChartConfig);
             var ddSeries = ddChartConfig.series;

             var series = this.series;
             var chart = series.chart;
             var drilldown = chart.options.drilldown;

             var seriesObjs = [];
             for (var i = 0; i < ddSeries.length; i++) {
                 if (!$.isPlainObject(ddSeries[i])) {
                     console.log(ddSeries[i]);
                     var j = (drilldown.series || []).length;
                     var seriesObj = null;
                     while (j-- && !seriesObj) {
                         if (drilldown.series[j].id === ddSeries[i]) {
                             seriesObj = drilldown.series[j];
                         }
                     }
                     if (seriesObj) {
                         seriesObjs.push(seriesObj);
                     }
                 } else {
                     seriesObjs.push(ddSeries[i]);
                 }
             }

             ddChartConfig.series = seriesObjs;
             ddSeries = ddChartConfig.series;

             // Fire the event. If seriesOptions is undefined, the implementer can check for 
             // seriesOptions, and call addSeriesAsDrilldown async if necessary.
             HighchartsAdapter.fireEvent(chart, 'drilldown', {
                 point: this,
                 seriesOptions: ddChartConfig
             });

             if (ddChartConfig) {
                 if (_holdRedraw) {
                     chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(this, ddChartConfig);
                 } else {
                     chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(this, ddChartConfig);
                 }
             }
         }

     });
 }(Highcharts));








 // Create the chart
 $('#container').highcharts({
     chart: {
         type: 'column'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     xAxis: {
         type: 'category'
     },

     plotOptions: {
         column: {
             stacking: 'normal'
         }
     },

     series: [{
         name: 'Yearly Orders',
         data: [{
             name: 'Location 1',
             y: 100,
             drilldown: {
                 series: ['l1-wa', 'l2-wa'],
                 subtitle: "subtitle",
                 xAxis: {
                     title: {
                         text: 'X Axis'
                     }
                 },
                 yAxis: {
                     title: {
                         text: 'Y Axis'
                     }
                 }
             }
         }, {
             name: 'Location 2',
             y: 150 //,
             // drilldown: 'l2-wa'
         }]
     }],
     drilldown: {
         series: [{
             name: 'Widget A',
             type: 'column',
             id: 'l1-wa',
             data: [{
                 name: 'Qtr 1',
                 y: 5,
                 drilldown: {series: ['l2-wb'],            xAxis: {
                 },
                 yAxis: {

                 }}
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 2',
                 y: 25
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 3',
                 y: 25
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 4',
                 y: 20
             }]
         }, {
             name: 'Widget B',
             type: 'line',
             id: 'l1-wb',
             data: [{
                 name: 'Qtr 1',
                 y: 10
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 2',
                 y: 5
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 3',
                 y: 5
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 4',
                 y: 5
             }]
         }, {
             name: 'Widget A',
             type: 'column',
             id: 'l2-wa',
             data: [{
                 name: 'Qtr 1',
                 y: 25
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 2',
                 y: 5
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 3',
                 y: 5
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 4',
                 y: 15
             }]
         }, {
             name: 'Widget B',
             type: 'pie',
             id: 'l2-wb',
             data: [{
                 name: 'Qtr 1',
                 y: 30
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 2',
                 y: 30
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 3',
                 y: 15
             }, {
                 name: 'Qtr 4',
                 y: 25
             }]
         }

         ]
     }
 })
 });
```

Here is a **JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/skTHx/10/

Comment: Right now it's not supported by drilldown.js plugin. We have plans to add this somewhere in the future (no ETA right now).

Answer (score 12):

You can refer this demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phdjsep/vNfWk/)

code:

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {

    var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
        categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
        name = ['Browser brands'],
        data = [{
                y: 55.11,
                color: colors[0],
                drilldown: {
                    categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                    series: [{
                        type: 'spline',
                        name: 'MSIE versions 2000',
                        data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                        color: colors[0]
                    },{
                        type: 'spline',
                        name: 'MSIE versions 2010',
                        data: [1, 5, 10, 15],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                y: 21.63,
                color: colors[1],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Firefox versions',
                    categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                    data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                    color: colors[1]
                }
            }, {
                y: 11.94,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Chrome versions',
                    categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                        'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                    data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                    color: colors[2]
                }
            }, {
                y: 7.15,
                color: colors[3],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Safari versions',
                    categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                        'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                    data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                    color: colors[3]
                }
            }, {
                y: 2.14,
                color: colors[4],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Opera versions',
                    categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                    data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                    color: colors[4]
                }
            }];

    function setChart(name, categories, data, color, type) {
        var len = chart.series.length;
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            console.log(chart.series.length);
            chart.series[0].remove();
        }
        console.log('a');
        if(data.series){
            for(var i = 0; i < data.series.length; i ++ ){
                chart.addSeries({
                    name: data.series[i].name,
                    data: data.series[i].data,
                    type: data.series[i].type,
                    color: data.series[i].color || 'white'
                });
            }
        } else {
                chart.addSeries({
                    name: name,
                    data: data,
                    type: type,
                    color: color || 'white'
                });
        }
    }

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Click again to view brands.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                            if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                setChart(null, drilldown.categories, drilldown, drilldown.type);
                            } else { // restore
                                setChart(name, categories, data, drilldown.type);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: colors[0],
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y +'%';
                    }
                }
            },
            spline: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            setChart(name, categories, data, 'column');
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: colors[0],
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var point = this.point,
                    s = this.x +':<b>'+ this.y +'% market share</b><br/>';
                if (point.drilldown) {
                    s += 'Click to view '+ point.category +' versions';
                } else {
                    s += 'Click to return to browser brands';
                }
                return s;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: 'white'
        }],
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        }
    });
});

});
```

Comment: nice solution. potential improvement would be to have the 'back' click not be based on point click on drilldown. would be great if it showed up as the'back' button of normal drilldown.

Answer (score 3):

Found a neat solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941011/highcharts-add-go-back-drill-up-button-when-drill)

Uses a drillup option,

```
 Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            drillUpText: '<< Go Back {series.name}'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for a drillup button in combination with the `setChart()` solution, can be to add a hyperlink (e.g. in a subtitle). Then give the original data to `setChart()`

```
$(document).on('click', '#drillup', function () {
    var data = {categories: categories, series: series};
    setChart('new title', categories, data, chart.type);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sample code for multiple series drill-down column and line charts.. 

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://github.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <script>
    $(function () {    

        // Create the chart
        // type to line for line chart
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Basic drilldown'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category'
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            color: 'white',
                            textShadow: '0 0 2px black, 0 0 2px black'
                        }
                    },
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Things',
                data: [{

                    name: 'Animals',
                    y: 5,
                    drilldown: 'animals'
                }, {
                    name: 'Fruits',
                    y: 2,
                    drilldown: 'fruits'
                }, {
                    name: 'Cars',
                    y: 4,
                    drilldown: 'cars'
                }]
            }, {
                name: 'Things3',
                stack: 1,
                type: 'line',           
                data: [{
                    name: 'Animals',
                    y: 8,
                    drilldown: 'animals3'
                }, {
                    name: 'Fruits',
                    y: 7,
                    drilldown: 'fruits3'
                }, {
                    name: 'Cars',
                    y: 10,
                    drilldown: 'cars3'
                }]
            }],
            drilldown: {
                activeDataLabelStyle: {
                    color: 'white',
                    textShadow: '0 0 2px black, 0 0 2px black'
                },
                series: [{
                    id: 'animals',
                    name: 'Animals',
                    data: [
                        ['Cats', 4],
                        ['Dogs', 2],
                        ['Cows', 1],
                        ['Sheep', 2],
                        ['Pigs', 1]
                    ]
                }, {
                    id: 'fruits',
                    name: 'Fruits',
                    data: [
                        ['Apples', 4],
                        ['Oranges', 2]
                    ]
                }, {
                    id: 'cars',
                    name: 'Cars',
                    data: [
                        ['Toyota', 4],
                        ['Opel', 2],
                        ['Volkswagen', 2]
                    ]
                },{
                    id: 'animals3',
                    name: 'Animals3',
                    type: 'line',
                    stack: 1,
                    data: [
                        ['Cats', 2],
                        ['Dogs', 3],
                        ['Cows', 1],
                        ['Sheep', 1],
                        ['Pigs', 1]
                    ]
                }, {
                    id: 'fruits3',
                    name: 'Fruits3',
                    type: 'line',
                    stack: 1,
                    data: [
                        ['Apples', 4],
                        ['Oranges', 3]
                    ]
                }, {
                    id: 'cars3',
                    name: 'Cars3',
                    type: 'line',               
                    stack: 1,
                    data: [
                        ['Toyota', 4],
                        ['Opel', 3],
                        ['Volkswagen', 3]
                    ]
                }]
            }
        })
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Add some explanation for understanding your answer

Comment: This answer will plot a column chart series with a second line chart series (which both have their own drill downs)