# Highcharts - drill down to multiple series in R

Tags: r, highcharts

I know this has already been answered in JS but I was hoping for a solution using highcharter in R.  [Highcharts - drill down to multiple series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563824/highcharts-drill-down-to-multiple-series?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I'm new to JS and also not that familiar with the highcharter library in R so any help would be greatly appreciated. The following code compiles but as the code is more experimental than anything it does not allow me to drill down to a multi- series chart as hoped.

```
DATABrowser = list(list(y= 55.11
                    ,drilldown = list(
                      name = 'MSIE versions',
                      categories = list('MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 
'MSIE 9.0'),
                      series = list(list(
                        type = 'spline',
                        name = 'MSIE versions 2000',
                        data = list(10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81)

                      ),list(
                        type = 'spline',
                        name = 'MSIE versions 2010',
                        data  = list (1, 5, 10, 15)
                      ))

                    )),list(y = 21.6),list(y = 11.6),list(y = 7.3),list(y = 
2.6)

)

categories = list('MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera')
name = 'Browser brands'



fn <-"function () {

var drilldown = this.drilldown;
var len = chart.series.length;
var name = null, catergories = drilldown.categories, data = drilldown, type 
=drilldown.type;
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
chart.series[0].remove();
}

if(data.series){
for( i = 0; i < data.series.length; i ++ ){
chart.addSeries({
name: data.series[i].name,
data: data.series[i].data,
type: data.series[i].type,
});
}
} else {
chart.addSeries({
name: name,
data: data,
type: type,

});
}
} 
"

hc = highchart() %>%
hc_chart(type = "column") %>%

hc_title(text = "Basic Drilldown Big Bossing") %>%
hc_xAxis(categories = categories) %>%
hc_add_series(
name = name
,data = DATABrowser
) %>%   hc_plotOptions(
column = list(
  # allowPointSelect = TRUE,
  cursor = "pointer",
  point = list(
    events = list(
         click = JS(fn)
    )
  )
)
)
hc
```

Comment: Have you had a look at http://jkunst.com/highcharter/docs/reference/hc_drilldown.html ? Why is it not applicable here? BTW the problem stem from the fact that the `chart` variable is not defined in the JS

Comment: the above example only has one series in the drill down, looking for something more like this http://jsfiddle.net/phdjsep/vNfWk/ .Do you know if there is a way to pass the chart variable to the funciton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS function returns an error

> chart is undefined

Indeed we don't have access to the chart from the click event, but we can retrive it with:

```
var chart = Highcharts.charts[0]
```

So putting that inside the JS, together with some typo fix gives us:

```
fn <-"function () {
  var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
  var drilldown = this.drilldown;
  var len = chart.series.length;
  var name = null, 
      categories = drilldown.categories, 
      data = drilldown, 
      type = drilldown.type;
  chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    chart.series[0].remove();
  }

  if(data.series){
    for( i = 0; i < data.series.length; i ++ ){
      chart.addSeries({
        name: data.series[i].name,
        data: data.series[i].data,
        type: data.series[i].type,
        });
    }
  } else {
    chart.addSeries({
    name: name,
    data: data,
    type: type,

    });
  }
} 
"
```

Giving us:

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%

  hc_title(text = "Basic Drilldown Big Bossing") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = categories) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    name = name
    ,data = DATABrowser
  ) %>%   hc_plotOptions(
    column = list(
      # allowPointSelect = TRUE,
      cursor = "pointer",
      point = list(
        events = list(
          click = JS(fn)
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

[image: First screen]
[image: Second screen]

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks a million for this.