# Highcharter Unlimited Drill down using R

Tags: r, data.table, r-highcharter

I looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249723/multiple-series-in-drilldown), [that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876449/highcharter-map-with-drill-down-ability?rq=1). I followed [this github method](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/blob/434aedede8328d8722a0342a8d6e6609a6eafe65/dev/drill-down-ex.R) check out [ISSUES](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/470) to help get ideas on how to solve this.

Step 1: Copy the following into text editor and save as **test.csv** file:

My datasource is [NVD JSON FEEDS](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds#JSON_FEED) which I processed and cleaned and created this dataset with the first 25 rows shown here.

```
Year,Vendor name,Product name,CVE,Major,Minor,Build,Revision
1988,eric_allman,sendmail,CVE-1999-0095,5,5.58,,
1988,ftp,ftp,CVE-1999-0082,*,,,
1988,ftpcd,ftpcd,CVE-1999-0082,*,,,
1989,bsd,bsd,CVE-1999-1471,4,4.2,,
1989,bsd,bsd,CVE-1999-1471,4,4.3,,
1989,sun,sunos,CVE-1999-1122,4,4.0,,
1989,sun,sunos,CVE-1999-1122,4,4.0,4.0.1,
1989,sun,sunos,CVE-1999-1122,4,4.0,4.0.3,
1989,sun,sunos,CVE-1999-1467,4,4.0,,
1989,sun,sunos,CVE-1999-1467,4,4.0,4.0.1,
1989,sun,sunos,CVE-1999-1467,4,4.0,4.0.2,
1989,sun,sunos,CVE-1999-1467,4,4.0,4.0.3,
1989,sun,sunos,CVE-1999-1467,4,4.0,4.0.3c,
1990,digital,vms,CVE-1999-1057,5,5.3,,
1990,freebsd,freebsd,CVE-2000-0388,3,3.0,,
1990,freebsd,freebsd,CVE-2000-0388,3,3.1,,
1990,freebsd,freebsd,CVE-2000-0388,3,3.2,,
1990,freebsd,freebsd,CVE-2000-0388,3,3.3,,
1990,freebsd,freebsd,CVE-2000-0388,3,3.4,,
1990,hp,apollo_domain_os,CVE-1999-1115,sr10,sr10.2,,
1990,hp,apollo_domain_os,CVE-1999-1115,sr10,sr10.3,,
1990,next,nex,CVE-1999-1392,1,1.0a,,
1990,next,next,CVE-1999-1198,2,2.0,,
1990,next,next,CVE-1999-1391,1,1.0,,
1990,next,next,CVE-1999-1391,1,1.0a,,
```

Step 2: Copy and paste following code into R and run it:

My codes follow [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192825/how-to-make-3-levels-drilldown-plot-in-r-highcharter-possible-other-packages?noredirect=1&lq=1) especially the discussion by `@NinjaElvis`. I think it is possible to create 3 levels or more. Just doing more research and figuring out.

```
############################
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("highcharter"))
library("dplyr")
library("purrr")
library("data.table")

second_el_to_numeric <- function(ls){

  map(ls, function(x){
    x[[2]] <- as.numeric(x[[2]])
    x
  })

}

cve_affected_product <- fread("test.csv")

# LAYER ONE YEAR DRILLDOWN VIEW #########################
Year <- cve_affected_product[,c(1:2)]
Year <- unique(Year[,list(Year,`Vendor name`)])
Year <- Year[,c(1)][,count:=1]
Year <- setDT(aggregate(.~ Year ,data=Year,FUN=sum))
#setorder(Year, Year, `Vendor name`)
years_df <- tibble(
  name = c(Year$Year),
  y = c(Year$count),
  drilldown = tolower(paste(name,'id'))
)

ds <- list_parse(years_df)
names(ds) <- NULL

# Vendor View HC ###########
hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_title(text = "Basic drilldown") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_yAxis(visible = FALSE,reversed = FALSE) %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      boderWidth = 0,
      dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    name = "Vendors",
    colorByPoint = TRUE,
    data = ds
  )


# LAYER TWO VENDOR DRILLDOWN VIEW #########################
Vendor <- cve_affected_product[,c(1:3)]
Vendor <- unique(Vendor[,list(Year,`Vendor name`,`Product name`)])
Vendor <- Vendor[,c(1:2)][,count:=1]
Vendor <- setDT(aggregate(.~ Year+`Vendor name` ,data=Vendor,FUN=sum))
setorder(Vendor, Year, `Vendor name`)

years <- as.character(unique(Vendor$Year))

for(i in 1:length(years)){
  tempdf <- Vendor[Vendor$Year==years[i],]
  dfname <- paste("df",years[i],sep="")
  dsname <- paste("ds",years[i],sep="")

  X <- tibble(
    name = c(tempdf$`Vendor name`),
    y = c(tempdf$count),
    drilldown = tolower(paste(name,'id'))
  )


  Y <- second_el_to_numeric(list_parse2(assign(dfname,X)))

  assign(dsname,Y)


}


# Vendor View HC ###########
hc <- hc %>%
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(
        id = "1988 id",
        data = ds1988,
        colorByPoint = TRUE,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "1989 id",
        data = ds1989,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "1990 id",
        data = ds1990,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      )#,
    )
  )

# LAYER THREE PRODUCT DRILLDOWN VIEW #########################
Product <- cve_affected_product[,c(1:4)]
Product <- unique(Product[,list(Year,`Vendor name`,`Product name`, CVE)])
Product <- Product[,c(1:3)][,count:=1]
Product <- setDT(aggregate(.~ Year+`Vendor name`+`Product name` ,data=Product,FUN=sum))
setorder(Product, Year, `Vendor name`,`Product name`)

vendors <- as.character(unique(Product$`Vendor name`))

for(i in 1:length(vendors)){
  tempdf <- Product[Product$`Vendor name`==vendors[i],]
  dfname <- paste("df",vendors[i],sep="")
  dsname <- paste("ds",vendors[i],sep="")

  X <- tibble(
    name = c(tempdf$`Product name`),
    y = c(tempdf$count),
    drilldown = tolower(paste(name,'id'))
  )


  Y <- second_el_to_numeric(list_parse2(assign(dfname,X)))

  assign(dsname,Y)

}
# Product View HC ###########
hc <- hc %>%
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(
        id = "eric_allman id",
        data = dseric_allman,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "ftp id",
        data = dsftp,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "ftpcd id",
        data = dsftpcd,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "bsd id",
        data = dsbsd,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "sun id",
        data = dssun,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "digital id",
        data = dsdigital,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "freebsd id",
        data = dsfreebsd,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "hp id",
        data = dshp,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "next id",
        data = dsnext,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      )#,
    )
  )

# LAYER FOUR CVE DRILLDOWN VIEW #########################
Product_CVE <- cve_affected_product[,c(1:5)]
Product_CVE <- unique(Product_CVE[,list(Year,`Vendor name`,`Product name`, CVE, Major)])
Product_CVE <- Product_CVE[,c(1:4)][,count:=1]
Product_CVE <- setDT(aggregate(.~ Year+`Vendor name`+`Product name`+CVE ,data=Product_CVE,FUN=sum))
setorder(Product_CVE, Year, `Vendor name`,`Product name`, CVE)

products <- as.character(unique(Product_CVE$`Product name`))

for(i in 1:length(products)){
  tempdf <- Product_CVE[Product_CVE$`Product name`==products[i],]
  ifelse(tempdf$`Vendor name`==tempdf$`Product name`,
         dfname <- paste("df_",products[i],sep=""),
         dfname <- paste("df",products[i],sep=""))

    ifelse(tempdf$`Vendor name`==tempdf$`Product name`,
         dsname <- paste("ds_",products[i],sep=""),
         dsname <- paste("ds",products[i],sep=""))

  X <- tibble(
    name = gsub("-", "", c(tempdf$CVE)),
    y = c(tempdf$count),
    drilldown = tolower(paste(name,'id'))
  )

  Y <- second_el_to_numeric(list_parse2(assign(dfname,X)))

    assign(dsname,Y)

}

# CVE View HC ###########
hc <- hc %>%
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(
        id = "sendmail id",
        data = dssendmail,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "ftp id",
        data = ds_ftp,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "ftpcd id",
        data = ds_ftpcd,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "bsd id",
        data = ds_bsd,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "sunos id",
        data = dssunos,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "vms id",
        data = dsvms,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "freebsd id",
        data = ds_freebsd,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "apollo_domain_os id",
        data = dsapollo_domain_os,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "nex id",
        data = dsnex,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      ),
      list(
        id = "next id",
        data = ds_next,
        keys = list('name','y','drilldown')
      )
    )
  )
```

Output First Level:
[image]

Output Second Level Clicking on 1988:
[image]

**ISSUES:**
I should be able to click on vendor **eric_allman** and get a drill down, however I am not. I want to be able to drill down all the way to Revision if it exists. This is just prototypying [new functionality for my app](https://kill3rbee.shinyapps.io/vFeedCard/) to get it working. However, highcharter does not make this easy or efficient. My dataset has almost 4 million observations. That will be the next struggle how to handle that.

I am even considering using [D3 by creating a JSON file in python](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663#index.html) if I cannot do it using R. However, creating the JSON file in python is not trivial but doable. I am currently working on python code as a back up.

Thank you for the help and any suggestions

Comment: It is ok to down vote a question because it is not clear or show lack of research. However, in doing so provide some feedback. Or could it be `you(whomever downvoted)` did not understand how to solve problem question? Some people are visual, so I provided working example so that when you play with it, you could understand my goal as stated in the `ISSUES` is to achieve 3 level drill down or more.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough after posting this question, i decided to do more research, since most of the research was pointing me to example of how to do it in javascript. Google search took me to [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55168485/r-highcharter-dynamic-drilldown-in-shiny-on-the-fly) by [`@K. Rohde`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5836932/k-rohde)
This post is from `2015` and I really appreciate how he explained the two different approaches. I ended up using hybrid approach borrowing from both.

For those interested in seeing how the drill down is working, [go to my shiny app](https://kill3rbee.shinyapps.io/vFeedCard/). Once you on the page `Click on Visualizations`, then `"Drill Down For Vendor CVE Affected Products Versions and Revisions"`and try it out. Again I would not have done it without `@K. Rohde` write up.